# How do I generate 300 lists of 12 numbers between 1 and 33 without repeats in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am conducting a study in which each of the 300 participants are rating 12 prototypes each. We have 33 prototypes in total. How would I generate 300 lists each containing 12 random prototypes from the 33 in excel ensuring that no list contains a duplicate and all prototypes appear at least 100 times?

Comment: This belongs to stackoverflow. It also needs to be retagged with the word 'algorithm'. I don't know if Excel can do this, but it's a rather simple task for a program.

Comment: This would be a trivial programming task, but very difficult to achieve in regular excel. VBA isn't difficult, and is inbuilt to excel!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the sort of thing Excel is good for, but you might be able to use the VB integration to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way:

1. Make 1 row for each Participant, starting in A2, using column A to put their   name/participant#.
2. Place one prototype per column in cells B1:AH1, then select and drag these down so that it fills each column for all 300 participants.
3. Write a macro that randomly deletes 21 cells between B1:AH1 for each row
4. Use sort in the tool menu to be able to check for duplicates

Comment: Dublicates.  Might have to add this to my dictionary, right next to automagically.

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement that each prototype must appear 100 times. If you're going to write a macro to delete cells, you'd be better off writing a proc that generates the lists and checks them in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

While it is definitely possible to do in Excel, it would be difficult since VBA is tricky to work with. If you need a more powerful spreadsheet tool you might want to look at [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/)

Comment: it's actually not difficult at all in VBA.